# How to draw text, like NSString draw(in:withAttributes:), with subpixel rendering?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, nsview

I've got some Cocoa views which use NSTextField, and they use the system's setting for subpixel rendering:

[image: NSTextField 3]

I've got some other custom Cocoa views that override `draw(_:)`, and use methods like NSString `draw(in:withAttributes:)` to draw their text, and these never use subpixel rendering:

[image: NSString draw() 3]

It doesn't look awful, but it does look different, and I want all my text to look the same.

My sample draw method is really simple:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    let attrs: [String: Any] = [
        NSFontAttributeName: NSFont.labelFont(ofSize: 12),
    ]
    "3".draw(in: bounds, withAttributes: attrs)
}
```

I tried everything I could find that looked at all related to subpixel rendering, at the top of my draw() method:

```
let ctx = NSGraphicsContext.current()!.cgContext
ctx.setShouldSubpixelPositionFonts(true)
ctx.setShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts(true)
ctx.setAllowsFontSubpixelPositioning(true)
ctx.setAllowsFontSubpixelQuantization(true)
ctx.setAllowsAntialiasing(true)
ctx.setAllowsFontSmoothing(true)
ctx.setShouldAntialias(true)
ctx.setShouldSmoothFonts(true)  // (this works, but only if the background is opaque)
```

but they had no effect.  Maybe I don't understand how graphics contexts work here.

Without instantiating an NSTextField, how do you draw text with subpixel rendering?

Comment: What happens if you specify a(n opaque) background color in the attributes? What happens if you override the view's `isOpaque` getter to return true and, of course, live up to that promise by filling the `dirtyRect` with an opaque color before drawing the string?

Comment: @Ken: With `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:NSColor.white`, then `ctx.setShouldSmoothFonts(true)` triggers subpixel rendering correctly (including following the system preference).  Reporting `isOpaque` also works, with the same context flag.

Comment: Great! Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I should have been more clear.  A transparent background is necessary for my program.

Comment: Is it possible to do subpixel-rendering, if you do not have a background? You need to mix-in a partial value to the existing background. If your view is transparent, the background is provided by another view (maybe of another window). You can mix-in with alpha. But alpha is related to the whole pixel, not to the subpixels. There is no green-alpha, red-alpha and blue-alpha. Therefore I think, that this cannot work.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: NSTextField does it.

Comment: Without having a background?

Comment: BTW: What happens, if you set the BG to white with a high transparency?

Comment: Yes, without a background.  That's the default case.  Put an NSTextField label on a gray window (or any other background), and you get subpixel rendering.

Comment: "White with high transparency" is an interesting result, but not quite right.  At alpha=0.1, I see some level of subpixel rendering.  At alpha=0.01, it's indistinguishable from the grayscale-only case.  It's kind of like it gradually turns down subpixel rendering as background transparency increases.

Comment: Ah, okay, I do not know why, but I understood it that way, that the window itself is transparent. Hmm, I do not see another way instead of going the "real" way ATS.

Comment: What is this "going the 'real' way ATS" you refer to?  I thought I was asking for the real solution all along!